# Macbook Pro won't turn on

Tags: macbook, troubleshooting, macbook-pro, black-screen-of-death

The macbook pro (just over a year old, so just out of warranty) won't turn on.  The battery is full, and the power cord lights up with an orange light.  Pressing the power button does nothing, but if I hold it for a few seconds, I hear the hard-drive click once and begin to spin, but then stop right away.

I already tried the suggestions on [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ts1365).

I've never worked on a mac before, but my guess would be shot motherboard.  Any ideas before I have it taken in?

Comment: Did you try with another battery or without battery?

Comment: @laurent: No I will do that tonight - any other troubleshooting tips?